# is it the angular cli version or angular version which is found in app-root tag in browser

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when I click on developer tools, I found ng-version = "some version"

in app-root  tag, I just want to know what is this version, is this the angular/cli version or angular/compiler-cli version or angular version???

Answer (score 1):

That Is the angular/core version. The angular cli version you can see in the console (ng --version) or in your package.json file.

Comment: that means is it not the exact angular app version?

Comment: what is this angular/core?

Comment: the angular/core is the main angular library, then you have more like angular/forms, angular/http...see your package.json file

Comment: So angular/core and angular application versions are the same, aren't they ?

Comment: Exactly. The angular cli is only a tool to generate projects, components, services, etc...and for building too

Comment: my angular/core version is 5.1.0 and angular/compiler-cli version is 5.2.11 in the developer tool it is showing 5.2.11 as ng-version

Comment: A good way to check your versions is to go to your package.json file. you can see both the @angular/cli and @angular/core versions